# How to initialize a list in C?

Tags: c

I need to keep a list to simulate memory management. The program assigns a certain number of bytes to a certain process - the processes are bogus, since there are no actual processes, but basically I am thinking all I need is a list of integers.

Currently I have:

```
#define ALLOCSIZE
#define *int[ALLOCSIZE]
```

I think that is right? My C class has a method:

```
initialize_memory(int size)
{

}
```

I don't want to use anything fancy, all I want is just a list of integers.

Comment: `DEFINE`? Do you mean `#define`?

Comment: you need to read a C book or tutorial! I think you meant an array not a list in your question. Also there are no classes in C. C is not an object oriented language.

Comment: Fixed your OP. But there are no classes in C. Is this actually about C++?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the DEFINES, you don't need them here.

Use calloc:

```
int* memory = (int*)calloc(bytes, sizeof(int));
```

You will need to free this memory when you're done with it:

```
free(memory);
```

See: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdlib/calloc/

Comment: This goes inside my initialize_memory block? And I don't need to pre-recare anything other than int *list in header?

Comment: Calloc returns a pointer to the new memory (which you can normally just use as an array) area, you need an int* variable to store the address. I would suggest avoiding the use of globals. Defining it within main() and pass it as an argument to any functions that need it is normally better. You will need to #include <stdlib.h> to make calloc available.

Answer (score 0):

If the size of the array (not list) is determined at runtime (i.e. it's not a constant in the code), then you have to malloc the list like this:

```
unsigned char *g_array;
initialize_memory(size_t bytes)
{
  g_array = calloc(bytes);
}
```

This will make g_array point to a chunk of memory `bytes` big.